# Error from Github pages “The file `css/main.scss` contains syntax errors” with default installation

Tags: css, ruby, sass, jekyll, github-pages

***My apologies that this is a similar to other issues filed. I've tried a number of the recommended fixes and nothing seems to be making a difference.***

I'm using the jekyll gem v 2.5.3 (my ruby version is 2.1.5p273) to generate a new Github pages jekyll blog. Without making any changes to the default install (`jekyll new`) in the root of the repository and pushed it to ghp. I then received the following build error from gh:

> The file css/main.scss contains syntax errors

The styles aren't compiling at all. As suggested in another reported issue I tried adding layout:null in the frontmatter section of main.scss but it doesn't seem to change anything. I've run `jekyll server --safe` and the site's css compiles fine locally. Because I'm new to jekyll and the ghp build process isn't transparent I'm at a loss for how to fix the problem. Any pointers would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I made a repo to showcase the problem. [Here's the code](https://github.com/phedinkus/sample-jekyll) and [here's the site](http://phedink.us/sample-jekyll/). When I run the server locally it looks like this: 
[image: Local rendering]

Comment: A repository url can be usefull to help you.

Comment: @DavidJacquel per your suggestion I made a sample repo and also uploaded a screenshot to show how the css gets compiled locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen on http://phedink.us/sample-jekyll/, it seems that your problem is solved for the scss to css generation. http://phedink.us/sample-jekyll/css/main.css

The only problem remaining is that your `baseurl` that is not set in ***_config.yml***.

`baseurl: /sample-jekyll`

Note : For now the loaded css is http://phedink.us/css/main.css